# Help with Proof of Hausdorffs Maximal Principle

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm going through the proof of Hausdorffs Maximal Princple (probably the most complex proof I've gone through to date) and hoping I can get some help. I've understood almost all of it but seem to have missed some part of the proof which is supposed to be easy.
The proof I am following is here: [http://www.cs.bsu.edu/~hfischer/math412/zorn.pdf](http://www.cs.bsu.edu/%7Ehfischer/math412/zorn.pdf)

The only part I can't get is here:
*The remainder of the proof consists of checking that for a fixed C ∈ E the set
F = {D ∈ T0 | g(C) ⊆ D ∨ D ⊆ C} is a tower. Properties (i) and (ii) are verified
as for the set E*

I can't get property (ii). Using the approach for set $\mathcal E$ doesnt seem to be  work (as $\mathcal E$ and $\mathcal F$ are different). I thought that since $C \in \mathcal E $ and we know $\cup \mathcal D \in T_{0}$ then either $\cup \mathcal D  \subseteq C$ or $C  \subseteq \cup \mathcal D$. And the former implies $\cup \mathcal D \in \mathcal F$ but I can't get  $C  \subseteq \cup D$ to imply $g(C)\subseteq \cup \mathcal D$ (or maybe this is not the way to do it). I think I am missing something basic as this is supposed to be easy!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got it. Seems like it isnt too hard and it is similar to the rest of the proof.
Suppose $\mathcal D \subseteq \mathcal F$ is a chain of chains. Then as $\mathcal F \subseteq T_{0}$ and $T_{0}$ is a tower, $\cup D \in T_{0}$. Now suppose $E \in \mathcal D$ then $E \in \mathcal F$ and so $g(C) \subseteq E$ or $E \subseteq C$.
Suppose $E \subseteq C$ for all $E \in \mathcal D$. Then $\cup \mathcal D \subseteq C$ and so $\cup \mathcal D \in \mathcal F$ and if there is one $E$ for which $g(C) \subseteq E$ then $g(C) \subseteq \cup \mathcal D$ and so $\cup \mathcal D \in \mathcal F$ hence the result.